# Weird in popup menu

Tags: android, kotlin, popupmenu

I have created a `menu` icon on action bar. When it is clicked, I expect it will show something like this

[image]

But it display on the left hand side instead.

[image]

What could be this issue ?

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            val id = item.getItemId()
            if (id == R.id.more) {
                var popup: PopupMenu? = PopupMenu(context!!, view!!)
                popup?.menuInflater?.inflate(R.menu.pop_up_menu, popup.menu)
                popup?.show()

                popup?.setOnMenuItemClickListener({ item: MenuItem? ->
                    when (item!!.itemId) {
                        R.id.logOut -> {
                        }
                    }
                    true
                })
            } else
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

            return true
        }
```

**fragment_menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/more"
          android:title="menu"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"/>
</menu>
```

**pop_up_menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/logOut"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Log Out"
    />

</menu>
```

The view  I passing is this

```
@Nullable
    public View getView() {
        return this.mView;
    }
```

Comment: strange enough.

Comment: post your R.menu file

Comment: Depends on what the `view` is that you're passing to PopupMenu constructor.

Comment: Ah wait just realised something: Why are you inflating the popup in `onOptionsItemSelected()`? Is this some kind of secondary menu? If not just put it `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: @AIMINPAN done.

Comment: @CodeRed post edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the **wrong** `view` as what @CodeRed mentioned.

Replace

```
var popup: PopupMenu? = PopupMenu(context!!, view!!)
```

to

```
val vItem = getActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.more)
var popup: PopupMenu? = PopupMenu(context!!, vItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Menu in ActionBar is populated automatically by system, you don't need to write code to populate it.

To achieve the menu like figure 1, fragment_menu should be like:

```
<menu>
  <item android:title="Search" />
  <item android:title="Locate" />
  <item android:title="Refresh" />
  <item android:title="Help" />
  <item android:title="Check for update" />
</menu>
```

onOptionItemSelected is used to handle when above menu is clicked, not used to show the menu.

popup menu is free position menu like right click menus in windows, not the one you expect in figure 1.

Comment: I want Logout display exactly like figure 1